# PHP: read html file for offline reading

Tags: php, javascript, browser

I am using `file_get_contents()` function to read a URL eg:

```
$html = file_get_contents('www.mydomain.com');
```

Now how do I modify above code or what should I do to read pages offline once saved in my db. The problem is that saved pages have images and css pointing to fetched url which means internet should be on to read them.

How can I make it have images as well as CSS also saved. I had asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139616/save-files-in-mht-mhtml-format-programatically) before regarding mht/mhtml format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1766-PHP-Build-MHT-MIME-archives-from-lists-of-files.html

http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2006/12/making-mht-single-page-archive-files-with-php

Please note that MHT is MS-specific format so above example uses Windows libraries.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this that is potentially dangerous (you'll have to sanitize inputs, if any), but will certainly work if your server is a well-equipped Linux server, is to invoke the `wget` program with the [right arguments](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget) using PHP's `system` function, like so:

```
system("wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites \
        --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent $url");
```

Once the files are downloaded, you can put them in the database, though I have to ask: what benefits does a database have over a file system for the purpose of storing files? Of course, I don't know your particular circumstances; I'm just raising the question in case you're making things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not using linux. Anyway to make it work on Windows or what other options could be ?

Comment: `wget` has [windows binary](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm  "Wget for Windows")